# Regex Expression To Search Full Text For Specic Fields

Tags: regex

Scanned invoice using UiPath and now have one full text string. Need Regex expression(s) that will allow me to pull just the values I want. Bolding the values I want.

Sample String Dump:
Dedicated Internet Access 3 5MISSISSAUGA 04/01/20 - 04/30/20 $250.00
Unlimited Usage T MISSISSAUGA
Unlimited Internet 30Mbps

MISSISSAUGA
04/01/20 - 04/30/20 $452.00

Subtotal: **$702.00**
867309189 ON HST $91.26

[Total Current Charges: **$793.26**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoIxM.png)
Thank you for choosing TeraGo
For invoice inquiries, please call 1-866-837-2461
or e-mail us at billing1@terago.ca

Terms are Net 30 days unless stated otherwise.
We strongly advise our customers to consider switching to EFT which is not
only faster and more reliable than checks-by-mail, but is also safer in the
current environment. Credit Card payments only accepted on accounts less
than $2,000. Pre-Authorized Debit is available. Contact us at the number or
e-mail above for more detail.

Electronic Funds Transfer detail:
Supplier name: TeraGo Networks Inc.
Bank Name: Royal Bank of Canada
Bank institution code: **004**
Bank Transit number: **06033**
Bank Account number: **10310780**
Swift Code: ROYCDOG2
Please email Remittance advice to: billing@terago.ca

Or
Please make cheque payable to:
TeraGo Networks Inc.
P.O. Box 8956

Page: 1
Invoice Date:

Invoice Number:
Customer No.:
To:

KEATON CRESCENT
3010923

Attn: JOHN SMITH

04/06/2020
205198

795780
Contract No.:

CURRENT CHARGES AND CREDITS
INVOICE

Comment: The part where it starts with electronic funds transfer detail, I assume that is some indented part? Can you post the raw text in a code block please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? This pattern assumes no comma delimited number in the dollar amounts. Your question lacks context for constraints.

```
^Subtotal: (\$\d+\.\d{2})\b(?:.|[\n\r])*Total Current Charges: (\$\d+\.\d{2})\b(?:.|[\n\r])*Bank Name:[^:]+: (\d{3})\b(?:.|[\n\r])*Bank Transit number: (\d{5})\b(?:.|[\n\r])*Bank Account number: (\d{8})
```